# Transfer database from one instance into an other

Tags: redis

I have a redis instance with data inside 2 databases: 0 and 1

I now have a second instance running and would like to transfer the data inside the first instance's database 1 into the second instance's database 0

Is this possible ?

Comment: I guess, you have one Master and two slaves to it, and You want to add another Master with some slaves. and want to sync between master and master. I this what you want to say ?

Comment: What's the version of your redis? If the redis is 2.8+, just use 'Scan' & 'MIGRATE'.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer here, but I'm facing a similar problem and one of the solutions I'm currently considering is writing a script with [rdbtools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) that would read the dump.rdb file and read the keys from a certain db and insert them to another redis instance.